# get first three elements of jagged array

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, jagged-arrays

My brain isn't working, I'm trying to grab the first three rows on this grid. I'm making a simple checkers game just to learn some new stuff. My code is grabbing the first three columns to initialize the placement of the red chess pieces. I want the first three rows instead.

This is what my code is doing now:

[image]

This is my (simplified) code. `Square` is a class of mine that just holds a few little items to keep track of pieces.

```
    private Square[][] m_board = new Square[8][];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_board.Length; i++)
        m_board[i] = new Square[8];


//find which pieces should hold red pieces, the problem line
    IEnumerable<Square> seqRedSquares = 
         m_board.Take(3).SelectMany(x => x).Where(x => x != null);
//second attempt with the same result
    //IEnumerable<Square> seqRedSquares = 
         m_board[0].Union(m_board[1]).Union(m_board[2]).Where(x => x != null);

//display the pieces, all works fine
    foreach (Square redSquare in seqRedSquares)
    {
        Piece piece = new Piece(redSquare.Location, Piece.Color.Red);
        m_listPieces.Add(piece);
        redSquare.Update(piece);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# LINQ". That's already in the tags.

Comment: @John Saunders, I don't have a strong opinion either way, but doesn't it make it easier to sort mentally if you're skimming the list of question titles?

Comment: People on [so] are used to using tags to filter the list of questions, so no, it doesn't. It just makes the question titles ugly and unreadable. Read it to yourself: "C# LINQ get first three elements of jagged array" vs. "get first three elements of jagged array". Which one makes sense and tells you something about the question, and which one just has stuff in front of it?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, ah, I see, you make a good point. I'll write clean titles in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `m_board.Take(3)` to get the first three columns, then this should give you the first three rows:

```
 m_board.Select(c => c.Take(3))
```

If you want to get the rows (or columns) as enumerables then do this:

```
var flattened = m_board
    .SelectMany((ss, c) =>
        ss.Select((s, r) =>
            new { s, c, r }))
    .ToArray();

var columns = flattened
    .ToLookup(x => x.c, x => x.s);

var rows = flattened
    .ToLookup(x => x.r, x => x.s);

var firstColumn = columns[0];
var thirdRow = rows[2];
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was close and dancing around the correct answer.

Comment: Also, never used .ToLookup() before. If I could up vote you twice, I would.

Comment: @jb. - Yes, `.ToLookup()` is quite awesome. Cheers.